# git desktop not working , can't push anything but '.gitattributes'

Tags: git, github

[image]

**Problem:** Lately, Github Desktop can't detect changes, or push anything but the .gitattributes file. It used to work just fine, but I've had this problem lately.

**Efforts:**

1. I tried pushing a different project.
2. I uninstalled Github Desktop and deleted local appdata, then I installed the latest version (1.6.1).

**solution:**

I learne some command line. I tried 'git init' on the project folder, then using the git desktop to add local folder. It worked . I don't know why.

Comment: I'm working on Win10 /64

Comment: tried pushing different project, even the ones used to succeed. but it dosn't work out.

Comment: Please provide a step by step guide to reproduce your problem starting from a clean installation of your desktop client.

Comment: What does the equivalent of `git status` state?  Git's not going to push anything that's not committed, and it's not going to care about anything that isn't staged.

Comment: git hasn't detect any changes like it used to ,so there is noting to commite.